# How can I detect if the user is on localhost in Eclipse / Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, server, localhost

I am trying to do this in my jsp file. If tomcat is deployed using localhost, I want a specific condition to follow in this case. How would I construct this kind of method and call this system/server property?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
${pageContext.request.serverName}
```

in your JSP file and check if it is 127.0.0.1 or "localhost" or something you want to check.

Comment: I got it working by doing: `String server = request.getServerName(); if (server.equals("localhost"))
 {%>
  <jsp:forward page = "newpage.jsp" />
 <%}`